# Recommended to Ubuntu, downloaded to a saved file on desktop

Tags: system-installation

So now what?

Old HP with XP, running IE8 and had to put Chrome into the mix because Yahoo quit working in IE. Still use the IE, because my online shop won't load with Chrome.
My AVG antivirus began having conniptions and to get System Restore to work again, Microsoft said to erase the antivirus software, which doesn't want to go (maybe another problem in itself?).

How do I open U and 'run it alongside' the others? I downloaded the 32 bit 12 LTS.
Not as tech savvy as I should be for this, but was hoping to keep it all working at least until I can afford another computer.
Thank you!

Comment: A side note: if your website only work in IE, you might want to hire someone to fix it for you, just saying

Comment: I have an online shop using someone else's website (Etsy). Their website will not work on my computer if I go to it using Google Chrome. I had to download Chrome in order to run Yahoo for my email, as Yahoo quit working in IE8.

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu has no support for IE8. However, you can run IE6 on Wine. If this is enough, you can switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Danatela  The website where I have my online shop will not support less than IE8. Thank you, tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Ubuntu Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) to install Ubuntu just like another program in Windows.  The link I provided has some instructions as well as a download link.

Once this is installed and configured, you can reboot into Ubuntu and switch back to Windows whenever you want to by rebooting and selecting Windows from your boot menu.